# Processing messages within a time window using Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

This code:

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError

settings = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'client.id': 'client-1',
    'enable.auto.commit': True,
    'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'}
}

c = Consumer(settings)

c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

try:
    while True:
        msg = c.poll(0.1)
        if msg is None:
            continue
        elif not msg.error():
            print('Received message: {0}'.format(msg.value()))
        elif msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
            print('End of partition reached {0}/{1}'
                  .format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
        else:
            print('Error occured: {0}'.format(msg.error().str()))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    c.close()
```

is taken from https://www.confluent.io/blog/introduction-to-apache-kafka-for-python-programmers

I'm attempting to update this code so that the topic is polled every second but stats for all messages within a window of 1 minute are processed.

This is how I plan to solve:

replace `msg = c.poll(0.1)` with `msg = c.poll(1)`

introduce a new variable `i` which will maintain the current number of messages for the given minute.

Create a new class SharedQueue to store the data to be processed:

```
class SharedQueue:

    data_queue = deque(maxlen=1000000)

    def append_data_queue(self, msg):
        self.data_queue.append(msg)

    def get_data_queue(self, record_key, record_value, timestamp):
        return self.append_data_queue
```

With the changes, the code becomes:

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError

settings = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'client.id': 'client-1',
    'enable.auto.commit': True,
    'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'}
}

sq = SharedQueue()

c = Consumer(settings)

c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = i + 1
        msg = c.poll(1)
        sq.append_data_queue(msg)
        if msg is None:
            continue
        elif not msg.error():
            print('Received message: {0}'.format(msg.value()))
        elif msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
            print('End of partition reached {0}/{1}'
                  .format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
        else:
            print('Error occured: {0}'.format(msg.error().str()))
        if i == 60: 
            //process the last 60 items of the queue.
            i = 0


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

But this is not a good solution as `poll` can return immediately if there are records available.

How can I implement processing of messages received within a time window? Am I on the right track implementing a queue?

Comment: 1) 60 messages won't necessarily all be in any such "time window" since you cannot gurantee the rate of consumption or production. 2) Surely you want to stop the loop when `i == 60` and resume when queue is empty?

Comment: If you did want such windowing semantics, PySpark or Flink might allow more control over such interfaces